# Compare $_POST returned values with term array

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to compare Post values returned from AJAX with available taxonomy term_id but somehow I am out of luck.
My $_POST['recvid'] values based on the user selection for example are '70=on&72=on&74=on' .

```
    if( $brands = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'recipebrands' ) ) ) :  //constructing array of available terms
    $brands_terms = array(); 
    
    foreach( $brands as $brand ) { //going thru all terms
                
     if( ????? ) // trying to compare if POSTED values are within available term array
           $brands_terms[] = $brand->slug;   //if yes, then build the array of all slugs
            }
        
 endif;
```

Somehow I am stuck within the if clause and cannot figure out how to build the $brands_terms array
I tried
`isset( $_POST['recvid'][$brand->term_id ] ) && $_POST['recvid'][$brand->term_id] == 'on')` but without luck.

Data from ajax contains 'recvid' variable:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: my_custom_vars.ajax_url,
                
                data: {
                    action: 'my_filter_function',
                    recvid: filter.serialize() // form data
                },
```

Yes I know, should be learning much more about these things :)

Comment: You reference `$_POST['recvid']` but I don't see that in your code.  Can you add more to this for more context?

Comment: Updated main topic

Answer (score 1):

Just check if $_POST contains key with id of correstponding term.

```php
if (isset($_POST['recvid'][$term->term_id])) {
```

However, I would not loop through all the terms. `get_terms` function has corresponding option. So, to receive all posted ids, you would do this (also note, that first parameter may be a string, no need for an array):

```php
$brands = get_terms('recipebrands', [ 
    'include' => array_filter(array_keys($_POST['recvid']), function($value) { return is_numeric($value); }),
]);
```

What above code does?

- `array_keys` returns $_POST array keys obviously.
- `array_filter` filters out only numeric keys (see anonymous function).
- `include` option of `get_brands()` allows you to specify exact ids of terms you require.